# My server has 4 ethernet ports. I'm running proxmox using a cluster. I want to have my nodes directly attached but on the same subnet

Tags: routing

I setup a bridge, that's fairly straightforward.  But then it occurred to me that none of my nodes are ever going to pull more than their own 1Gb worth of bandwidth from the server and I have 2 nodes and 1 NAS that are all 1Gb.  So I thought why not use these directly to the server (unfortunately the switch I bought is 10/100, I do have a Gb router with 4 ports that I'm utilizing at the moment, but that limits the # of connections I can uplink from the 4 nic server, [i.e. I'm only using 1 atm]).

So what I'd like to do is hook up my 2 nodes to 2 ports, and the NAS to 1 port, but all these devices (with the exception of the NAS) need to talk to each other.  When they are on a switch, no big deal, but on the ports bridging doesn't do the job.  I read I need to enable routing.

However, all the examples I have for routing are for routing separate networks.

Right now this is what I have

Server (Node 1): 192.168.3.18
Node 2: 192.168.3.20
Node 3: 192.168.3.22
NAS: 192.168.3.19

How should I setup my networking if I want these devices to remain on the same network but I simply want the server's NIC's to act as as switch?  I imagine I'd have eno1 dedicated with an ip 192.168.3.18, but am unsure if I need to set ip's on eno2 eno3 and eno4.  I'm thinking I need to, but again am unsure on how the routing commands should look like

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
                slaves eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
                bond-mode 802.3ad

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
                address 192.168.3.18
                netmask 255.255.255.0
                gateway 192.168.3.1
                bridge_ports bond0
                #bridge_ports eno1
                bridge_stp off
                bridge_fd 0
                bridge_maxwait 0

#auto en02
iface eno2 inet manual
        #address 192.168.3.14
        #netmask        255.255.255.0

iface eno3 inet manual

iface eno4 inet manual
```

Comment: Could you explain why "bridging doesn't do the job"? Because that's exactly the kind of scenario bridging is for. In general, it's very painful to have several network interfaces on one machine connected to the same subnets. That's why all examples you've seen avoid this scenario. It can be done with extra effort, but you really don't want to, unless you can explain why "bridging doesn't do the job".

Comment: If I bridge the adapters.  I need to connect all 4 ports to a switch.  At the moment my switch is 10/100 so that's not an option.  I have a 4 port ethernet 1GB router.  I can connect 4 devices to it.  So I can't bridge the ports and connect to that without kicking off my other devices.  Bridging means it treats all 4 nics as a single nic.  When I bridge them, I have one ip and traffic is split out all the ports.  But when I set this mode (i.e. I enslave the other eno adapters in /etc/network/interfaces), if I connect another machine directly to an enslaved port.  I can't ping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
                #slaves eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
                bond-mode 802.3ad

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
                address 192.168.3.18
                netmask 255.255.255.0
                gateway 192.168.3.1
                bridge_ports bond0 eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
                #bridge_ports eno1 eno2 eno3 eno4
                bridge_stp off
                bridge_fd 0
                bridge_maxwait 0

#auto en02
iface eno2 inet manual
        #address 192.168.3.14
        #netmask        255.255.255.0

iface eno3 inet manual

iface eno4 inet manual
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I bridge the adapters. I need to connect all 4 ports to a switch.

No, you don't. That's what

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
```

is for: It implements a "software switch", where you can have all 4 ports externally facing as part of the "switch", and `br0` as internally facing port.

So you can achieved the same thing in software, and the throughput limitation is the speed of the NICs that serve as ports for this "switch".

> Bridging means it treats all 4 nics as a single nic.

No. It means you have a software switch with one internally facing NIC. Just like if you'd only use one NIC, connect it to a switch, and connect the other devices to the switch.

> But when I set this mode (i.e. I enslave the other eno adapters in /etc/network/interfaces), if I connect another machine directly to an enslaved port. I can't ping it.

I don't know what you've done in `/etc/network/interfaces`, and why it didn't work for you.

It should, and the way I do it usually is to first use `ip` to set up everything, and once it works, I make it permanent in `/etc/network/interfaces`, or otherwise.

If you cannot ping, then debug: Make sure everyone got a proper IP address (i.e., login to one of your nodes and verify), use `tcpdump` whereever you can (including on your node) to see where packets get lost, use `ip route get` to verify routing, etc.

---

You are **bonding** your ports, you are not **bridging** them.

These are very different things. In particular, for bonding to work, you need a corresponding bonding construction on the other end of the pair (usually it's only a pair) of connections. Which you don't have, so it's no surprise nothing works.

Remove the bond, add all NICs as port to the bridge.

Comment: I've updated my question with my /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: well after months of working with the bond it broke today and I think I found a proper bridge guide. https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections